# Flutter Firebase Admob: AdView not Destroy on Page Navigation

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, admob

I'm trying to dispose adview while navigating to a video player page.

I used

```
_bannerAd?.dispose();
_bannerAd = null;
```

to destroy the davies but the ad is still shown on the new page. I discovered that using `Navigator.pop` before `Navigator.push` solve the issue but i don't want to pop the previous page.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you may check in the build function

```
if(ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent){
  _bannerAd..show();
}
```

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311407/flutter-how-to-check-if-a-widget-page-is-rendered)