# how to know whether the screen is in front or background

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to know the screen(StatelessWidget) is in front or background.
for now, a screen in background shows AlertDialog, but i want to show the dialog only when the screen is in front.
is there any way to do that?

here's my code using hooks_riverpod.
i omitted some lines because of "mostly code" warning.

```dart
final _provider = provider801x;

class MyPage801x extends HookConsumerWidget {
  MyPage801x({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final String? message = ref.watch(_provider).message;

    if (message != null) {
      ref.read(_provider).done();
      showResult(context, message); //don't want to show when in background.
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('main screen'),
        ),
        body: Container(),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showResult(BuildContext context, String message) async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async {
      await showOKOnlyDialog(context, message: message);
    });
  }
}
```

```dart
final provider801x = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose((ref) => Notifier801x(ref));

class Notifier801x extends ChangeNotifier {
  Notifier801x(this._ref) {
    _iapManager = IAPManager4Android();
    _refreshDataset();

    _iapListener = _iapManager.onChangedIAP.listen((IAPTransactionStateEnum state) async {
      _message = state.message! + ' @801x';
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  String? _message = null;
  String? get message => _message;

  void done() {
    _message = null;
  }

  void _refreshDataset() {
    //fetch data
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: could you share your code

Comment: @Delwinn added my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code worked!

```dart
     if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent ?? false) {
        showResult(context, message);
     }
```

I got this answer from the page below. thank you all!

[Flutter | How to know if widget is on top of navigation stack (visible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70151891/flutter-how-to-know-if-widget-is-on-top-of-navigation-stack-visible)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mounted` for this case.
`mounted` is true if the widget is visible to the user or technically on the top of the stack of screens otherwise will be false.

So, you can use it like this way

```
if(mounted){
    //do your stuff like show dialog or snackbar
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! but, i'm using HookConsumerWidget(StatelessWidget), not StatefulWidget.

Comment: @momongarZ have you found any solution for it so far ?

Comment: the answer has been posted by the author

Answer (score 0):

Use a static string (or DI ) in main function , set it to class name in build function of any screen. check this variable to know which screen is visible.